# Need like in_array but not need full match

Tags: php, arrays

```
$input1 = "aa b";
$input2 = "aa bb";
$input3 = "aa bbb";
$input4 = "aa bb cc";
$input5 = "ab";
$input6 = "abc";
$input7 = "ab c";
$input8 = "abcd";
$input9 = "test";

$check = array("aa bb cc", "abc", "testing");

new_in_array($input1, $check); //output: false
new_in_array($input2, $check); //output: true
new_in_array($input3, $check); //output: false
new_in_array($input4, $check); //output: true
new_in_array($input5, $check); //output: false
new_in_array($input6, $check); //output: true
new_in_array($input7, $check); //output: false
new_in_array($input8, $check); //output: false
new_in_array($input9, $check); //output: false
```

How can like this?

Had already been all lowercase and half width.

I dont know how to explain clearly, so I use coding to explain, hope we can understand, thanks

Please help!!

Comment: And your $check array have one element/one string?

Comment: use **strpos()** instead of in_array()

Comment: Why does `$check` need to be an array? Seems this question hardly has anything to do with arrays. In summary, you want `aa bb cc` to match `aa bb` and/or `aa bb cc`, but not `aa b` or `aa bbb`, right?

Comment: To nevermind: will more than element.
To donald123: Thanks, I try later.
To deceze: Because I need check with an array, I change my question later

Comment: Rob Allen recently posted a [blog](http://akrabat.com/php/substr_in_array/) about this very thing

Comment: to @MarkBaker: Thanks, but not well for me

Comment: Why not well for you? Doesn't it do what you expect? In what way doesn't it work? You need to clarify your needs.

Comment: To @MarkBaker, According to my example for your recommended function, $input1,2,4 output: true, $input3 output: false. But I want the result is $input1, 3 output: false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$input1 = "aa b";
$input2 = "aa bb";
$input3 = "aa bbb";
$input4 = "aa bb cc";
$input5 = "ab";
$input6 = "abc";
$input7 = "ab c";
$input8 = "abcd";
$input9 = "test";

$check = array("aa bb cc", "abc", "testing");

var_dump(new_in_array($input1, $check)); //output: false
var_dump(new_in_array($input2, $check)); //output: true
var_dump(new_in_array($input3, $check)); //output: false
var_dump(new_in_array($input4, $check)); //output: true
var_dump(new_in_array($input5, $check)); //output: false
var_dump(new_in_array($input6, $check)); //output: true
var_dump(new_in_array($input7, $check)); //output: false
var_dump(new_in_array($input8, $check)); //output: false
var_dump(new_in_array($input9, $check)); //output: false

function new_in_array($needle, array $haystack)
{
    $needle = '/\b' . preg_quote($needle) . '\b/';
    $filtered = array_filter($haystack, function ($item) use ($needle) {
        return preg_match($needle, $item);
    });

    return !empty($filtered);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop and use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)/[stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) (depends on if you want it case sensitive). Should be something like this, however I didn't run the code to test it:

Edit: I changed the parameter order to match [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
function new_in_array($needle, $haystack)
{
    foreach($haystack as $i)
    {
        if(stripos($i, $needle) !== false)
        {
            return true;
        }    
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Thanks your help, but this function is not well.According to my example, $input1,2,4 output: true, $input3 output: false

Comment: it's because "aa b" is part of "aa bb". If you want to check whole words you need to alter the function and explode $needle.